# How to make weighted random sampling for matrix - MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, probability, sampling

I would like to create a weighted sample from a m by n matrix starting from an excel file ("DataTab", please see image 1).

First column (UGT) represents the ID of the matrix and the column B-F represent the probability associated to the variable "fi" for each UGT.
"fi" is a scalar that has value 10, 20, 30, 40, 50: this means that UGT 1101 has 50% of probability to have value 10 or 20, the UGT 1102 has can be 30 (50%) or 40 (50%), so on.

[image: Image 1]

I used "randsample function" that works only for scalar, and I cannot be able to use it for my situation.

```
fi = [10,20,30,40,50];
p = [0.15,0.20,0.30,0.10,0.25];
n=10000;
sample = randsample (fi, n, true, p);
hist(sample,fi);
bar(fi,n*p,0.7);
```

I put the entire code which works correcty with "Fv2" variable, not working with "Fv1" which is the goal of my question.

```
Nsample = 10; 
DataTab = xlsread('Scenari_stabilita_R6.xlsx','S1','A2:f6');
Ugt   = csvread('raster_ugt.acs'); 
UgtV   = reshape(Ugt,[],1);
MRas   = [UgtV];
MCycle  = MRas(~idxNaN,:);
a=unique(MCycle(:,4));
idxDataTab=ismember(DataTab(:,1),a);
DataTab2 = DataTab(idxDataTab,:);
nUGT = length(a);    
fi = [10,20,30,40,50];
Fv = [];
    for i = 1:nUGT
        Fv1 = randsample (fi, Nsample, true, DataTab2(i,:));
        %Fv2 = (DataTab2(i,3)-DataTab2(i,2)).*rand(Nsample,1) +
        %DataTab2(i,2); % this line calculates uniform distribution and
        %it has to be modified into weighted sampling
        Fv = [Fv,Fv1];
    end
```

The "Fv1" variable must be like this (without first row that I show only as example to better understand):

[image: Image 2 - final risults]

Anyone can help me, please?

@obchardon I have to answer here after running on R2019b version:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcLe4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncHGN.png)

The issue is that "p" comes from an excel file, so it can not be written as a scalar. How can I fix this?
Furthermore the frequencies of "fi" in first column do not respect the input probabilities. With this code, the frequencies are respected, but in somehow you should change "p" for each ugt.

```
sample = randsample (fi, n, true, p)
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to `cumsum()` your probabilty vector, generate `n` random number between `0` and `1` and check at which position the cumsum vector start to be smaller or equal to the random number:

```
% INPUT
n  = 10
fi = [10,20,30,40,50]       % given number
p  = [0.3,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.1
      0.5,0.5,0  ,0  ,0 ].' % given probability

% COMPUTATION
sp = size(p)     
rd = rand(n,1,sp(2))                   % 10x1x2 random number between 0 and 1.
cp = reshape(cumsum(p),1,sp(1),sp(2))  % cumulative probability
[~,ind] = max(rd<=cp,[],2)             % Get the position where rd start to be smaller or equal to cp.                     
res = squeeze(fi(ind))                 % Extract the corresponding value
```

With

```
res =

   50   20
   30   20
   10   20
   10   10
   30   10
   10   10
   10   20
   40   10
   10   20
   30   20
```

We just have to add a 3rd dimension to `rd` and `cp` so they can be broadcasted.

```
% Broadcasting along the first and second dimension
rd = 10 x 1 x 2
     ↓    ↓
cp = 1  x 5 x 2
```

Comment: Dear obchardon, as you can see from figure 1, i do not have a vector of p, but a matrix which values change for each ugt. So I think your suggestions are not suitable for my situation.

Comment: @MichelePapasidero have you, at least, run the code above ? `p` is a 2D array.

Comment: From your second image, where you do not take into account my comment that are not part of the code, it looks like you're using a very old matlab version. Broadcasting is only available for Matlab version 2016b and above.

Comment: I did it, please see my answer above.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service, it is designed to give a general answer to a general problem. After that, if you can not adjust the code for you specific case you should hire a developer or read some tutorial.